# Getting the length of a nested JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
            {
            "wordsacross": [
                {"ACHE": [
                    { "letter":"A" , "square":"A1" }, 
                    { "letter":"C" , "square":"A2" }, 
                    { "letter":"H" , "square":"A3" },
                    { "letter":"E" , "square":"A4" }
                ]},
                {"OPT": [
                    { "letter":"O" , "square":"A6" }, 
                    { "letter":"P" , "square":"A7" }, 
                    { "letter":"T" , "square":"A8" }
                ]}
            ],
            "wordsdown": [
                {"ALPHA": [
                    { "letter":"A" , "square":"A1" }, 
                    { "letter":"L" , "square":"B1" }, 
                    { "letter":"P" , "square":"C1" },
                    { "letter":"H" , "square":"D1" },
                    { "letter":"A" , "square":"E1" }
                ]},
                {"BRO": [
                    { "letter":"B" , "square":"G1" }, 
                    { "letter":"R" , "square":"H1" }, 
                    { "letter":"O" , "square":"I1" }
                ]}
            ]
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "query.words.php",
                data: { puzzleid: vPuzzleId },
                async: false
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                vWords = JSON.parse( msg );
                console.log(vWords);
                console.log("There are "+vWords["wordsacross"].length+" words across");
                for(var i=0;i<vWords["wordsacross"].length;i++)
                {
                    console.log( vWords["wordsacross"][i].length );
                    console.log( vWords["wordsacross"][i][0]["square"] );
                }
            });
```

I am trying to print out the content of all square items to the console. Both of my attempts at console.log are coming out undefined. How am I to access each square and print it to the console?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what will happen if you add the code `console.log(msg)` before the line `vWords = JSON.parse( msg );`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vWords['wordsacross']` or `vWords.wordsacross` (equivalent) contains one array with two elements. When you write `vWords['wordsacross'][i]` you're accessing a single one of those items. You're then trying to access `length` or `[0]` of that single item, but the item is not an array, it is an object.

For `i = 0` it is an object that has a property named `ACHE` and *that* is an array.

You may thus write:

```
vWords.wordsacross[0].ACHE.length
```

The way your object is structured, the property containing the array of letters is a different one for each item in the array, which may be a bit inconvenient. You could get enumerate the object's own properties with `Object.keys(vWords.wordsacross[i])`, but I'd recommend changing your object, if that's an option.

For instance, one item in the `wordsacross` array could have a `word` property for which the value would be `ACHE` and a `letters` property for which the value would be your array of letters. In that way, you could access `vWords.wordsacross[i].letters` without having to know that the word happens to be `"ACHE"`:

```
"wordsacross": [
    {"word": "ACHE",
     "letters": [
        { "letter":"A" , "square":"A1" }, 
        { "letter":"C" , "square":"A2" }, 
        { "letter":"H" , "square":"A3" },
        { "letter":"E" , "square":"A4" }
    ]}
],
```

Since the letters `"A"`, `"C"`, `"H"`, `"E"` can be inferred from the word `"ACHE"` you may be able to get away with just writing:

```
"wordsacross": [
    { "word": "ACHE";
      "squares": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]
    }
]
```

The string `"ACHE"` can be treated as an array of characters; you can get it's `length` and you can access the carachter at any given position, `wordsacross[0].word[i]`.

Comment: Yes I think the object needs to be changed then. I don't really know what it should look like though.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/xp8Ww/

```
for(var i=0;i<vWords["wordsacross"].length;i++)
            {
                var keys =Object.keys(vWords["wordsacross"][i]);
                console.log(keys.length);
                for(var j=0;j<keys.length;j++){
                    var keys2=vWords["wordsacross"][i][keys[j]].length;
                    for(var k=0;k<keys2;k++){
                      console.log(vWords["wordsacross"][i][keys[j]][k]["square"]);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `vWords.wordsacross` only (no brackets) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (key in vWords) { //Iterate for wordsacross and wordsdown
    console.log(key);
    var words = vWords[key]; //Get the value for wordsacross and wordsdown
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { //Iterate over the words
        for (word in words[i]) { //Iterate over the word object
            console.log(word);
            var wordSquares = words[i][word]; //Get the letter and square info for word object
            for (var j = 0; j < wordSquares.length; j++) { //Iterate over the letters
                console.log(wordSquares[j].letter);
                console.log(wordSquares[j].square);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will iterate over all the words in the results and print the letter and squares accordingly